# Get image url google cse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-custom-search

I am trying to retrieve images from JSON CSEand no success, I am able to retrieve title and description by

```
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++)
{
    var item = response.items[i];
    var title = item.htmlTitle;
...
```

But I am not able to query image url from JSON, here is JSON schema:

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "",
   "title": "",
   "htmlTitle": "",
   "link": "",
   "displayLink": "",
   "snippet": "",
   "htmlSnippet": "",
   "cacheId": "",
   "formattedUrl": "",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "",
   "pagemap": {
    "product": [
     {
      "name": "",
      "image": "",
      "description": ""
     }
    ],
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": ""
     }
    ],
```

I tried:

```
item.pagemap.product.image
item.[pagemap][product].image
item.product.image
etc
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like product is an array. Have you tried item.pagemap.product[0].image ?

Comment: Sorry, does not help. Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined